# How to fix memory leak in InputManagerImpl

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I installed LeakCanary to fix some memory leaks in my app. Some of them i managed to fix, but I am running out of ideas on a particular one, leaking the Activity context.
I absolutely don't know how the RecyclerView.mContext could be referenced by the InputMethodManager. Any hint is welcome!

[image: LeakCanary trace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mainly this issue comes when we use RecyclerView in the fragment associated with FragmentStatePagerAdapter in that activity , TreeObserver or something related with InputMethodManager being used.

Even after onDestroy() of that main activity is being called the app keeps the reference of that activity as it is referenced by InputMethodManager indirectly.

So, we cannot fix it, as it’s due to the bug in Android Source code

## take a look at this article

[Android Memory Leaks InputMethodManager Solved](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-memory-leaks-inputmethodmanager-solved)

I hope this help

Comment: @stoefln Updated 